# Sharing large library of Photos and Videos (currently in iPhoto) in different macs at home

Tags: backup, photos.app, photos, file-sharing, nas

currently I have iPhoto on my mac (mountain lion). the library is more than 350 GB (and growing fast). It is only on my computer, but my wife wants to have acces to the pictures too, not only photostream. She has an older mac book (white) running lion.

My idea was to centralize the library (NAS) and solve 3 problems at the same time (space on my laptop, and acces to more than 1 user, and backup of the photos (currently on my time machine)). As far as I know, it is not possible to store the iPhoto library on a NAS... So, what alternatives are there? I know picasa, they have a light app for mac, but aren't there any other alternatives? I don't want to split the library.

I currently use faces and places... and I would like to keep this features. I also like to share pics with my friends via photostream, but this can easily be replaced with other services.

Thanks

Comment: iPhoto (and it's big brother, Aperture) do NOT like when multiple people share the same library.

Comment: @jnovack I know that... that's why I'm looking for alternatives :-)

Comment: It depends a bit on if you use the more advanced features of iPhoto. If you are using the option to tag faces, or for example if you like to see where a picture is taken based on GPS coordinates or manually entered information, I personally do not know a good alternative. However, if you just want to browse the photo's, why not get rid of iPhoto and just organize your photos in different folders for different events, starting with for example the data. You could put this on your NAS. Not only would you be able to access it from your Mac,s but also other OS's and smartphone(s).

Comment: @Vincent I updated the question. I use faces and places, and I would like to keep such features.

Comment: I think I will give picasa a try... I just got it working... it's not that fancy as iPhoto, but I think it could do well with pictures stored on a NAS via apple share.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use something like AeroFS to sync the folder with the iphoto library across the two computers? You will probably still want to avoid making edits at the same time but at least you will have access to the library on two computers.